# Value assigned inside a function variable is always empty

Tags: bash, function, variable

I have the following simple script. In this script, I am assigning a value to a global variable inside a function. I can clearly see that the value is being assigned to the variable via a debug statement. However, when I echo the variable at the end, it's always empty.

```
function getValue()
{
local key=$1
local configFile=$2
keyValuePair="$(egrep "$key" "$configFile")" 

if [ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Cannot find the value for the specifed key"
    return 1;   
fi

value="$(cut -d"=" -f"2" <<< "$keyValuePair")"
echo "$value"
return 0;
}
function configuer()
{
if [ ! -f "$RMCFGFILE" ]
then
    echo "Cannot file RMGCFG file."
    return 1;
fi

#Recyclebin configuration
value=$(getValue "recyclebin" $RMCFGFILE)
if [ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$value"
    return 1;
fi

RECYCLEBIN="$value" **#### I am assigning here**
return 0;
 }
RECYCLEBIN=
RMCFGFILE="/home/sas/.rm.cfg"
LOCALEFILE=""
CONFIG_RESULT=$(configuer)

if [ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
echo "$CONFIG_RESULT"
exit 1;
fi

echo "Configuration success"
eval echo "Recyclebin: ${RECYCLEBIN}" **##No value**
```

Does anyone see what's going wrong here??

Comment: Which of the multiple functions and variables are you talking about? What debug statement are you refering to?

Comment: What are you expecting `value=$(getValue "recyclebin" $RMCFGFILE)` to do?

Comment: I think `RECYCLEBIN= ; ... ; echo "$RECYCLEBIN"` is the problem - You assign it the `''` null string. You could try `echo "${RECYCLEBIN+set but empty}"` to find out. But get rid of `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting:

```
CONFIG_RESULT=$(configuer)
```

To assign a value to `$RECYCLEBIN` because you...

```
RECYCLEBIN="$value"
```

... in the `configuer()` function. It's true that the function *does* assign a value to `$RECYCLEBIN` but that value only persists for the duration of the `$(`subshell`)` in which you set it. It will *not* apply any changes to its parent shell's environment - which is where you call it. When you:

```
eval echo "Recyclebin: ${RECYCLEBIN}"
```

`eval` parses all of its arguments out into a space separated string and attempts to run the results as a shell command. So `"${RECYCLEBIN}"` disappears because - in the current shell environment - it was last set to the `''` null string like:

```
RECYCLEBIN=
```

So on its execution of the statement all it does is:

```
echo Recyclebin:
```

Which is functionally no different than...

```
echo "Recyclebin: ${RECYCLEBIN}"
```

...anyway because `$RECYCLEBIN` is empty.